# Use sed/regex to rename a file - bash with macOS

Tags: regex, bash, sed, rename

I have a list of files that a date has been added to the end.
ex: Chorus Left Octave (consolidated) (2020_10_14 20_27_18 UTC). The files will end with .wav or .mp3

I want to leave the `(consolidated)` but take out the date. I have come up with the regex and tested with regexr.com. It does format the text correctly there.

The regex is: `/(\([0-9]+(.*)(?=.wav|.mp3))+/g`

Now, I am trying to actually rename the files. In my terminal I have cd'ed into the folder with the files. Based on other answers here I have tried:

1. `rename -n '/(\([0-9]+(.*)(?=.wav|.mp3))+/g' *.wav|*.mp3` - using `rename` installed with homebrew
2. `sed '/(\([0-9]+(.*))+/g' *.wav|*.mp3`
3. `for f in *.wav|*.mp3; do mv "$f" "${f/(\([0-9]+(.*)(?=.wav|.mp3))+/g}” done`

The first two do not throw any errors, but do not do any renames (I know that the -n after `rename` just prints out the files that will be changed, it doesn't actually change the files)

The last one starts a bash session.

I'd rather use the rename or sed, seems simpler to me. But, what am I doing wrong?.

Comment: bash isn't an OS

Comment: I know, but you can use bash on linux and such, so I wanted to specify that I am on OS - I'll update to make it clearer

Comment: of course bash must be run on an OS like Linux or FreeBSD... It can't run on bare metal. There's still nothing clearer after the edit. In fact you shouldn't use things like bash on the title, it's the job of the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

pat='([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9] UTC)'
for f in *.mp3 *.wav; do echo mv "$f" "${f/$pat}"; done
```

Remove the `echo` preceding the `mv` after making sure it will work as intended. You may also consider adding the `-i` option to the `mv` in order to avoid clobbering an existing file unintentionally.

Comment: So this worked well on mac, which I was testing it on, now I need to do it on windows. Do you know what that script would be? I do have bash installed with v 5.0.17(1), I have added `set` before `pat` and I have tried several scripts on google/here that have not worked.

Comment: @BethStevic Sorry, I don't have a clue how to do that on windows.

Comment: No worries! Thank you so much for the previous script, it gives me something to go off of